How can I avoid duplicate posts when using pagination in MongoDB?
I am building a blog web app where I want to display posts on the home page. I am currently using MongoDB to retrieve posts based on tags.
I want the data of the home page to be random and mixed between the latest posts and popular posts.
the problem is that I don't know to prevent duplicate data when getting more data
I am using Express with Mongo as a database.
So after 2 pages, I started getting data I already had.
I did handle it in the front-end (react)
But I want a way to handle it in the back-end
like what other websites do.
I used this as an example.
the second request is supposed to return data but ignore data returned in the first request (page)
db.test.aggregate([ { $match: { tags: { $in: ["python", "java"] } } }, { $sample: { size: 10 } }, { $project: { text: true } }]).toArray()


You can use the concept of Seeded Random Shuffling.
The functionality you are trying to make is that two users get different random view of results. And same user may also get different result when he visits next time.
Instead of randomizing in query, you can create a criteria (integer or string) which captures how your data is randomized.
For ex, lets say my criteria is that I right shift my array by an integer k.
Hence, for k=2
my array 19, 25, 4, 8, 10 becomes 8, 10, 19, 25, 4
my array indices 0,1,2,3,4 becomes 3,4,0,1,2.
I will randomly generate this k on first request and then pass this k to client which will then use this k in subsequent requests, and server would always get the same array when sorting using the same k.
If per Page=2,
when page=0, I generate k=2, it would give 8,10, I also pass this k in response.
when page=1 and k=2 in request, i sort according to k, it would give 0,1.
The biggest concern would be choosing a complex criteria, where array indices are shuffled and you would have to first fetch all records from mongodb and filter in javascript which would ultimately result in higher response time.

The brute force way would be to send the ids of records already fetched in other pages and filter those in mongo query.
